# XQuery to append node to existing node set

Tags: xslt, weblogic, xquery

I am new to working with XQuery and XSLT. WebLogic is using XQuery 1.0.

I have a WebLogic composite and I have a collection of nodes and just want to add a node to an existing node set in an XQuery assignment. My current solution seems too heavyweight. I will be dealing with tens of thousands of records and it seems to me there should be a really easy way to just insert a node under another node and return it.

```
declare function local:func($svdPpl as element() (:: element(*,  sv:svdPpl) ::), 
                            $svdPsn as element() (:: element(*, sv:svdPsn) ::)) 
                            as element() (:: element(*,  sv:svdPpl) ::) {
   <sv:svdPpl>
   {for $psn in $svdPpl return $psn} {$svdPsn}
   </sv:svdPpl>
};
```

If I understand XQuery correctly that means millions of loops just to add records to existing node sets. I have tried using the insert node $svdPsn into $svdPpl syntax but that is causing validation errors in the WebLogic editor.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In my understanding XQuery 1.0 is a declarative language that operates on sequences of nodes and atomic values, it does not have loops at all. And node sets is a term of XSLT and XPath 1.0. Do you want to add an element node as a child of another element node? How does your XML input look, how the XML you want to add, which is the result you want?

Comment: @MartinHonnen XQuery is not typically considered declarative. There are loops and conditionals. Technically defined as a query language, it is very much like a functional language, however, especially XQuery 3.0, which introduces higher order functions.

Comment: @wst, well, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery lists `declarative` as one of the paradigms of the language and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming says "Common declarative languages include those of database query languages (e.g., SQL, XQuery)". The only use of the word "loop" in the XQuery 1.0 spec I can find is in a comment. A FLOWR expression is not a loop in my view.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Wikipedia's definition of declarative programming is incredibly broad. You can and generally do control program flow in XQuery, which is why I think the association is incorrect. XQuery defines itself as a query language in the spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XQuery is a functional language and variables are immutable. It's not possible to change the value of a variable once an assignment has been made using standard XQuery.

There is an extension to XQuery that allows updates called [XQuery Update Facility](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/), but not all processors implement it. I'm not familiar with WebLogic, but it looks like some versions support it. That would be the direct route.

Failing that, a common pattern is to write a generic recursive `typeswitch` function that walks the tree and applies transformation logic as it generates a modified copy of the input. This is how things work implicitly in XSLT. It's unclear from your question exactly how that would be implemented, but just as an example:

```
declare function local:add-after(
  $context as item(),
  $target-name as xs:QName,
  $payload as item()*
) as item()*
{
  typeswitch ($context)
  case element() return (
    element { node-name($context) } {
      $context/@*, 
      for $n in $context/node()
      return local:add-after($n, $target-name, $payload)
    },
    if (node-name($context) = $target-name)
    then $payload
    else ())
  default return $context  
};
```

Given an XML node `$xml` with a value of:

```
<x>
  <y>
    <z></z>
  </y>
</x>
```

You could use the above function `local:add-after($xml, xs:QName('y'), <payload/>)` to add a payload after the `<y>` element:

```
<x>
  <y>
    <z></z>
  </y>
  <payload></payload>
</x>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for.